# Querying multiple values with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, httprequest, alamofire

I want to check both username and password. I'm using mLab API. Checking just username with query is working but when I also add password. It doesn't work (whether I give wrong value, It returns OK (HTTP 200)).

API Document;

http://docs.mlab.com/data-api/

```
  let parameters: Parameters = ["q" : "{\"uname\" :\"\(tfUsername.text as! String)\" }, {\"password\" :\"\(tfPass.text as! String)\"}", "apiKey": "2ABdhQTy1GAWiwfvsKfJyeZVfrHeloQI"]


    Alamofire.request("https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/mysignal/collections/Cusers", method: .get, parameters: parameters,encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseData{ response in
        print(response.response?.statusCode)
```

Comment: As API Document states, you have to provide API key. Why would you send username and password?

Comment: @YakivKovalsky API Key is to connect to database. I'm connecting to database and check the credentials from the CUsers table. (I try to :))

Comment: So you have credentials in response.result.value of your completion block, right?

Comment: Yes. For example one table I have "uname" : "emre123", "password": "emre"

Comment: Then you should perform username / password check on response value. It has nothing to do with sending username / password as parameter.